# How to understand the word "exponent"?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

I have some difficulty in understanding the complex exponential function. So I decide to review the good old exponent function which I learned long ago.

I look up the word `exponent`, the [online dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exponent?s=t) says this:

> noun
>
> 1. a person or thing that expounds, explains, or interprets: an exponent of modern theory in the arts.
> 2. a person or thing that is a representative, advocate, type, or symbol of something: Lincoln is an exponent of American democracy.
> 3. Mathematics. a symbol or number placed above and after another symbol or number to denote the power to which the latter is to be
>      raised: The exponents of the quantities xn, 2m, y 4 , and 3 5 are,
>      respectively, n, m, 4, and 5.

I am not a native English speaker. To me, these 3 meanings are so distinct. Why are they sharing the same word `exponent`? I think the subtle relations among these 3 meanings may help me better understand the *human rationale/subconsciousness* behind the mathematical concept.

### ADD 1

According to [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/power.html), the exponent part is also called index, or power. I think the latter ones are more acceptable.

[image]

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @IanMiller Thanks for the reminding. I did considered that site. But I am a bit afraid if it will get enough explanations in a *mathematical* way.

Comment: While some math terms are related to everyday meanings, many are not (normal, field, ideal etc). I don't see the other meanings of *exponent* being related to the math one in any meaningful way, subtle or not. That said (and as suggested already) http://ell.stackexchange.com/ will likely provide more insights on the history and appropriation of *exponent* in math.

Comment: If the question were re-framed as "When and why did powers come to be called 'exponents'?" it might be a good fit for http://hsm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @mweiss I didn't know that site until now. I will try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are not the first to ask that question (perhaps in the stackexchange network you do).

Googling a bit: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110145007/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65184.html)

> Looking up the context of this sentence in Smith, I find that it
> follows a table of powers of 2:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
1   2   4   8  16  32  64  128 256
```

> He says (in Latin), "Just as, by addition, (in the upper row) 3
> [added] to 5 makes 8, so (in the bottom row), by multiplication, 8
> [multiplied] by 32 makes 256".  [...] So the words "exponent" refers to > the number in the top row
> corresponding to a given number in the bottom row; this is the number
> of 2's multiplied to make the given number--what we today would  call
> its base-2 logarithm, or the exponent of 2 that gives the number.

In short, it's impossible to know the exact meaning or reason of choosing *exponent* instead of any other word. I don't think you'll be able of deducing the intrinsics of Smith's mind from their explanations when choosing *exponent*, because he died five centuries ago.

Comment: Nice find. From the [same page](http://www.pballew.net/arithme8.html#power) linked off that answer: "*In mathematics, power refers to the number arrived at by raising a number to an exponent. In the mathematical expression 3^2=9, three is the base, two is the exponent, and nine is the power. Students often refer to the exponent as the power, but this is not historically correct, although it has become so common, even among many teachers, that some dictionaries refer to the power as the exponent.*".

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for pointing that out. I was one of those who refer to the exponent as the power...

Comment: Some more quotes from the same page as @dxiv *"POWER appears in English in 1570 in Sir Henry Billingsley's translation of Euclid's Elements: 'The power of a line, is the square of the same line.' "*

Comment: @smwikipedia Most of us use *power* and *exponent* interchangeably  nowadays in contexts where there is no potential for confusion. FWIW I don't recall seeing the *exponent* called *index* in US-English, but that may be just my anecdotal ignorance ;-)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/681425)

Comment: @Scientifica Done.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Well done!

Answer (score 2):

The common thread in the three definitions is that an exponent is something which *increases or highlights* a thing.   To make something larger, or more clear.

> 1.a person or thing that expounds, explains, or interprets: an exponent of modern theory in the arts.

They are people or things which seek to increase or highlight knowledge.

> 2.a person or thing that is a representative, advocate, type, or symbol of something: Lincoln is an exponent of American democracy.

They are people or things which seek to increase or highlight principles; by example or through leadership.

> 3.Mathematics. a symbol or number placed above and after another symbol or number to denote the power to which the latter is to be raised: The exponents of the quantities $x^n, 2^m, y^4$ , and $3^5$ are, respectively, $n, m, 4,$ and $5$.

They are things (mathematical operations) which increase the values.   Albeit, *in mathematical usage* an exponent may perhaps do so *negatively*, depending.

Comment: It may also have something to do with the fact that *power* was used since the Greeks, and there was a need to differentiate the [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) from the [power function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_function) .